# Why does bi-linearity in the free action mean some terms will go to zero in the Taylor expansion of the moment generating stochastic path integral?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-integrals

$Z[J,\tilde{J}] = \int DxD\tilde{x} \exp(-S[x,\tilde{x}] + \int J x dt + \tilde{J}\tilde{x} dt) $ is the moment generating function for a stochastic path integral. We may approximate this function by splitting the action $S[x,\tilde{x}]$ into a "Free Action", $S_F$, and an "interaction action", $S_I$, and then taylor expanding the exponential around the free action, for example

$Z[J,\tilde{J}] = \int Dx D\tilde{x} e^{-S_F} (1 + (\int \tilde{x}x^2 dt + \int \tilde{x}^2 x dt + \tilde{x}(0) + \int J x dt + \int \tilde{J}\tilde{x} dt) + \text{higher order terms}) $

where $S_F =\int \tilde{x} (\dot{x}+x) dt$.

However, I become confused by the next claim: if the Free action is bilinear in $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ then only terms with an equal number of $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ factors survive? Would anyone be able to expand on this maybe with an example?

Comment: Isn't the free action _quadratic_  in $\dot x$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how the example $S_F$ is quadratic in $\dot{x}$?

Comment: I thought that "free-action" means the action of a free particle.

Comment: At the moment I am reading from the PDF here: https://mathematical-neuroscience.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13408-015-0018-5

Comment: The stochastic path integrals are supposed to work for quite general stochastic differential equations I think.

Comment: As far as I can see they just claim the free action for the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck Process is $S_F$ without really explaining why this part of the total action is chosen to be free.